# position: absolute not doing what I expect

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am having problems getting the grasp of `position: absolute`

I understand that it positions itself according to the position of its relative parent. So what is wrong with my example? when clicking on the first ".col-lg-6", why is the faded blue line not centered on the right col?

Please could you rework the code and explain why this is happening?

```css
.formWrapper
{
    background: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

.formWrapper .contactForm
{
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
    <div class="formWrapper">
        <div class="contactForm row">
            <div class="col-lg-6"><h1>HI</h1></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6"><h1>HI</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I can't rework the code and give you what you want exactly, because I don't see the faded blue line you're talking about. But, I will explain what is going on with your code, as I see it.**

---

HTML Markup

```
 <div class="formWrapper">
     <div class="contactForm row">
         <div class="col-lg-6"><h1>HI</h1></div>
         <div class="col-lg-6"><h1>HI</h1></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
.formWrapper
{
    background: blue;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You have a `.formWrapper` div colored blue. It takes up the full screen, and you've positioned it relative. Positioning it relative provides an anchor for its child element to use when defining its own position as absolute (necessary).

```
.formWrapper .contactForm
{
    width: 750px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: yellow;
}
```

You've defined the a fixed width and height of the yellow `.contactForm` div and colored it yellow.

By defining `position: absolute`, with `top:50%` and `left:50%`, the top left position of the `.contactForm` div would appear in the very middle of the .formWrapper div. However, you've also added the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` style, which moves the `.contactForm` div to the left 50% of its own width and up 50% of its own height.

## Important

The `position: absolute` style that you've set in the parent of the `div.col-lg-6` elements does not affect the children's positioning within that element. Position absolute only directly affects the actual element to which you've applied this style, changing its position in reference to its own parent, or the closest parent that has a position style defined.

### Position Fixed

If your goal is to have a pop up that sits in the center of the screen, then you might want to use `position: fixed`, which positions the element relative to the window. This way you don't have to worry about the effects of other elements.

You could position the popup in the middle of the view the same way you positioned the `.contactForm` div in the middle of the its parent div.

#### Bootstrap

If you are using bootstrap or any other css framework, you may want to consult their documentation on how to accomplish your goals. Frequently, when using a css framework, adding your own custom styles that affect the sizes and positioning of elements can have consequences that are difficult to manage.

By setting a position of absolute or fixed, you might break the expected flow of the rest of the css. So, only do it when there is no standard way of doing what you need and you know the consequences.

Comment: Hi, That's correct, So it is going to be a centered form that pops up. I have added a clearer image of the "outlined box" I am talking about. This pops up when clicking the div col-lg-6 in my editor. it should should wrap around the left half of .contactForm should it not? I understand now that position absolute only affects the direct element you apply it too but then how would one use the bootstrap grid system inside that element if you know what i mean?